# Color change in Chrome and Opera after resuming from suspend

Tags: google-chrome, suspend, colors, opera, webkit

I have noticed several times that the color handling on one of my monitors were a bit off from time to time and thought it was the monitor itself, until today. When I "accidentally" dragged a tab out to its own window the color changed back to "normal".

[image: the bug]

Closing and re-opening the browser fixes it permanently for that session, but this is such a weird bug that I felt the need to share it. It is most likely not *Chrome* related as I have also seen it in Opera (maybe webkit related then?), but it is possibly a X bug or something?

Anyway, I would love some inputs and/or help finding the right place to file this bug.

Edit: this also affects Opera, so maybe a webkit related bug?

Edit 2: this only seems to happen when I suspend the laptop when it's not docked, then resume it when it's docked. If I don't close the browser window, suspend the laptop and undock it, then resume it again, the colors are fine again.

[image: Bug in Opera]

Comment: I'm on my phone but I believe you can check the **gamma** settings of all displays using `xrandr -q` and note the values when suspending and resuming. The gamma settings or other **xrandr** values *might* provide some clues to what is going on.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Wouldn't it have to be window-specific (like in the GIF above) as the color/gamma seems to be okay in one window but not the other?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Either way I am not seeing any gamma info with `xrandr -q` unfortunately. I get the different displays listed and their supported resolutions plus update frequencies.